# flutter socket.io chat app using nodejs as backend

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

i am currently working on chat app using socket.io..i have two funtion send and subscribe by send function i can send new message to anther user and by subscribe i add that message to the list...i have a database for storing these conversation....
Now my question is that how can i show all the conversation in list as well as the new message that is added to the list???
i tried by adding conversation messages and new message to the same class but it does not show me anything
Hope it will be enough explaination..

Comment: both send and subscribe funtion is working but i have two function One for conversation and on for new message ...The only thing i want to show conversation as well as the new send message

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [stomp_dart_client](https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_dart_client) library

For connection :

```
StompClient client = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig(
        url: 'wss://yourserver',
        onConnect: onConnectCallback
    )
);

client.activate();
```

For subscribe:

```
client.subscribe(destination: '<subscribe path>', headers: {}, callback: (data) {
    print(data.body);
})
```

For Send:

```
client.send(destination: '<subscribe path>', body: 'Message body', headers: {});
```